# Editor HTML feito em HTML

Tags: html, editor-de-texto

Preciso de um editor HTML, como este http://www.quackit.com/html/online-html-editor/full/ para alterar entre o modo visual e o modo HTML.

O problema é que procuro no google, procuro por códigos prontos e não encontro absolutamente nenhum código ou tutorial de como fazer o mesmo.

O plugin precisa alterar entre o modo visual e o HTML e o modo visual pode ser editado. (Como no exemplo do link).

Alguém conhece alguma ferramenta pronta para edição HTML? Lembrando que tem que ser feito em HTML pois eu irei colocar o editor online.

Se souberem, postem o código HTML e JavaScript  de um editor simples ou o link do mesmo.

Comment: Esse plugins são Jquery Felipe.

Comment: @Marconi é inviável fazer algo do zero em Jquery, gasta muito tempo. É melhor pegar algum já pronto.

Comment: Sim, isto que eu faço. Eu uso o scEditor, pra mim o mais simples e bonito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CkEditor ?
http://ckeditor.com/

Talvez funcione pra você.

Mas esse que você postou não é só clicar na opção **Source** do editor ?

Comment: Este que eu postei é online, eu precisava para por no meu sistema mesmo (logo online não é valido, pois vou trabalhar com formulários).

Este ckeditor eu testei ele, ele funciona porém o css não funciona corretamente. O online tem uma formatação melhor. 

Porém se eu não achar nenhum melhor serei obrigado a usar o CkEditor mesmo. Se puderem me ajudar a achar algum com uma formatação melhor eu agradeço.

Comment: Oloco. http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

Comment: Este em bootstrap é muito bom, porém é preciso dar suporte a postar o HTML, pois a pessoa irá colocar o template html e formatar visualmente.

Comment: Eu achei este, me parece bom. Só não entendi direito como usa-lo uma vez que não tem um exemplo HTML depois que faz o download. Acredito que vou ter que ir para o manual.

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php